# What is the difference between NetFx45WebLink and NetFx45RedistLink

Tags: .net, wix, wix3, bootstrapper, wix-extension

I used WiX 3.7 to write a bootstrapper which installs .net 4.5 first and then my application's MSI:

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Redist"/>
  <MsiPackage Id="MainAppPackage"
              After="NetFx45Redist"
              SourceFile="..\bin\Debug\MyApp.msi"/>
</Chain>
```

The [WiX documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm) says that `NetFx45Redist` is a standalone setup while the `NetFx45Web` is a web setup. After I built the bootstrapper with Id set to `NetFx45Redist` it had the same size compared to when I build it with `NetFx45Web` Id specified. I was curious so I downloaded the WiX sources (v3.7). I was surprised to see that there was little difference between the two `PackageGroup` elements.

The `DownloadUrl` for `NetFx45Web` is http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225704, while the one for `NetFx45Redist` is http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225702. According to the `RemotePayload\@Size` attribute `NetFx45Web` is 1005568 bytes and `NetFx45Redist` is 50352408 bytes.

I expected that `NetFx45Redist` will include the .net 4.5 setup in my bootstrapper and no download will be required. I see that's wrong. Which `PackageGroup` should I use then and what is the difference between the 2 downloaded .net 4.5 installations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both package groups are authored to download the files from Microsoft. Both provide full setups of Microsoft .NET 4.0 frameworks. The smaller one is a bootstrapper that then downloads just the pieces the system is missing. The larger one has all the pieces any system might need.

It is a bit surprising that WixNetFxExtension doesn't offer a non-download package group. But, since you have already peeked into the `NetFx4.5.wxs` source code, it should be a simple matter to copy the attributes that you want into your own package group.

EDIT:

I should also point that a bootstrapper takes command-line arguments as described [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Running-Burn-driven-installer-in-quiet-mode-command-line-parameters-td5913001.html). `-layout dvd` would download packages to a folder named `dvd`, which can be used for off-line installation. (Obviously, NetFx45Web wouldn't be appropriate for that.)

Comment: I played with it a bit and here is what I found: 1) when the web installer is downloaded it takes up less space but during repairs the whole .net framework needs to be downloaded again if it is missing 2) when the standalone installer is downloaded it takes up around 50mb more (which is reflected in the size of the application in Programs and Features) but during repairs download is not required.